# How do I change the forground color of a disabled UWP ComboBox?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, styling

I have a ComboBox which may be disbaled due to some application logic.
My issue is that the content of the ComboBox is barely visible if it is disabled.
So what i would like to do is to change the forground color when the ComboBox is diabaled.

I haven't found any easy way to do it within XAML.
I'd appreciate the helf, if somebody can help me out.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully changed the forground color by simply overriding the `ComboBoxForegroundDisabled` key entry in the `Page.Resouces` tag.

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="White" x:Key="ComboBoxForegroundDisabled" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In UWP, most controls have their own control templates. For some stateful complex controls, such as `ComboBox`, if you want to modify the style of a certain state, you need to modify its control template.

This is a complete ComboBox style:

```xml
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="MyComboBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,5,0,7" />
    <Setter Property="MaxDropDownHeight" Value="504" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <CarouselPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="OverlayOpeningAnimation">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.0" />
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.383" KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" Value="1.0" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="OverlayClosingAnimation">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.0" />
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.216" KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" Value="0.0" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </Grid.Resources>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundDisabled}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                To="1"
                Duration="0" />
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundBorderBrushFocused}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundFocused}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundFocused}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForegroundFocused}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusedPressed">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                To="1"
                Duration="0" />
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundFocusedPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource ComboBoxPlaceHolderForegroundFocusedPressed}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForegroundFocusedPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DropDownStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Opened">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <SplitOpenThemeAnimation OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder"
            ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter"
            OffsetFromCenter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset}"
            OpenedLength="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Closed">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <SplitCloseThemeAnimation OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder"
            ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter"
            OffsetFromCenter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset}"
            OpenedLength="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditableModeStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxFocused">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="DropDownGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxEditableDropDownGlyphForeground}" />
                                    <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Margin" Value="0,3,2,2" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxFocusedOverlayPointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="DropDownGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxEditableDropDownGlyphForeground}" />
                                    <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxFocusedDropDownBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Margin" Value="0,3,2,2" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxFocusedOverlayPressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="DropDownGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxEditableDropDownGlyphForeground}" />
                                    <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxFocusedDropDownBackgroundPointerPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Margin" Value="0,3,2,2" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxOverlayPointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxOverlayPressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBackgroundPointerPressed}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxUnfocused" />

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
        FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}"
        FontWeight="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeFontWeight}"
        Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxTopHeaderMargin}"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Visibility="Collapsed"
        x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" />
                    <Border x:Name="Background"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
        Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
        MinWidth="{ThemeResource ComboBoxThemeMinWidth}" />
                    <Border x:Name="HighlightBackground"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Background="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundUnfocused}"
        BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundBorderBrushUnfocused}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
        Opacity="0" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock"
          Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
          Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource ComboBoxPlaceHolderForeground}}" />
                    </ContentPresenter>
                    <TextBox x:Name="EditableText"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBoxStyle}"
        Margin="0,0,0,0"
        Padding="10,3,30,5"
        BorderBrush="Transparent"
        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
        PlaceholderText="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
        Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource ComboBoxPlaceHolderForeground}}"
        Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Visibility="Collapsed"
        Header="{TemplateBinding Header}"
        AutomationProperties.Name="{TemplateBinding AutomationProperties.Name}"
        x:Load="False"/>
                    <Border x:Name="DropDownOverlay"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Background="Transparent"
        Margin="0,2,2,2"
        Visibility="Collapsed"
        Width="30"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        x:Load="False"/>
                    <FontIcon x:Name="DropDownGlyph"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
        IsHitTestVisible="False"
        Margin="0,10,10,10"
        Foreground="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForeground}"
        FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
        FontSize="12"
        Glyph="&#xE0E5;"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="DescriptionPresenter"
        Grid.Row="2"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDescriptionTextForegroundBrush}"
        Content="{TemplateBinding Description}"
        x:Load="False"/>
                    <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                        <Border x:Name="PopupBorder"
          Background="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBackground}"
          BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownBorderThickness}"
          Margin="0,-1,0,-1"
          Padding="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownBorderPadding}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
            Foreground="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownForeground}"
            MinWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownContentMinWidth}"
            VerticalSnapPointsType="OptionalSingle"
            VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near"
            HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
            VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
            IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
            IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
            IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
            BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}"
            ZoomMode="Disabled"
            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">
                                <ItemsPresenter Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownContentMargin}" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>

                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

By querying the keyword `Disabled`, we can find the corresponding status:

```xml
<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundDisabled}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderBrushDisabled}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundDisabled}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundDisabled}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundDisabled}}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForegroundDisabled}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

All you need to modify is here:

```xml
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundDisabled}" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Change Value to the color you need.

**How to use**

You can put this ComboBox Style in `Page.Resources` tag or `Application.Resources` tag.

Add the following code on the required ComboBox:

```xml
<ComboBox IsEnabled="False" Style="{StaticResource MyComboBoxStyle}">
    <!--combo box items-->
</ComboBox>
```

---

In addition, the style code of the control will change with the system version. Some of the attributes in the above style are only available in the system version of 1809 and above. All control styles are stored in the `generic.xaml` file, you can click on a system resource reference in XAML at will, and press F12 to jump to the file.

Thanks.

Comment: thank you so much for the explaination! Do you have to copy the whole sytle tag or is it possible to shorten it?

Comment: The most appropriate way is to copy the entire Style code, because we can not modify the default style of the control, but we can use the new style to override it. In order to maintain your control style library, you can create a resource dictionary to store similar styles and introduce them in `App.xaml`. About the content of the resource dictionary, you can check it in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references#merged-resource-dictionaries)

Comment: I see, thank you!
One more thing I tried to change the forground color but it didn't work:
`<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If this does not work for you, then you may have to deal with your `ComboBoxItem`. If you customize `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` (such as a `TextBlock` with a Foreground of red), then the final displayed is red. Only when the control in the internal `DataTemplate` does not explicitly set the Foreground, the `Foreground` acting on the **ContentPresenter** will take effect. You can determine this by writing a simple `ComboBoxItem` inside the ComboBox, like `<ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True" Content="Test" />`